# SQL Server Service Broker Performance Impact

Tags: sql-server, service-broker

I'm curious to understand from all folks using SQL Server Service Broker, if there is any sort of degraded performance on your SQL Server due to enabling of this internal message broker mechanism?

We want to introduce a business use case to capture data change on certain tables asynchronously.

However, an argument has come up that enabling SSSB and having SQL Server now perform additional mechanism of all that it goes into the creation of all SQL broker objects like messages, queues, services, contracts, etc., followed up by execution of this additional internal messaging mechanism, may impact the overall performance of SQL synchronous business transactions under the pressure test.

I would like to hear your experience if any.

Comment: Just for the forum to know, I had posted the question here too. Have got one answer.https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/7cc6493e-466e-4dcb-a35e-ac4cdc4daac4/performance-impact?forum=sqlservicebroker#7cc6493e-466e-4dcb-a35e-ac4cdc4daac4

Comment: That you're saying that SQL will have to manage message types, queues, etc suggests that you might be using SQLDependency (which uses Service Broker but is not *just* Service Broker). Is that the case? Otherwise, all of the "stuff" that you need to implement "regular" Service Broker should be a one-time operation and after that it's just processing messages.

Comment: See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/196770/sql-server-service-broker-vs-rabbitmq/196782#196782